# Multiple Components with same state name, how to change one state of one component without affecting the others?

Tags: react-native, async-await, components, local-storage

In my react native program I have component (Bell) that is called for every item/list called from an API. The bell is used to make a notification (and cancel it)on press and I made a state (isBellActive) to determine if the Bell has been toggled on or not. If it is, isBellActive is true and false otherwise. Im storing the data via asyncStorage.

The problem im having is that if I change the state of one bell(on one item/list) and then close the app and relaunch, that state change from that bell will affect all the other bell component's isBellActive state. How to make it so the state (even though they all share the same name) are kept for one specific item/list

**Bell Component Class**

```
export default class Bell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      isBellActive:  null,

    };
  }

  componentDidMount = ()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem('isBellActive').then(value => this.setState({ isBellActive: JSON.parse(value) }));
  }

  setTrue(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem('isBellActive', JSON.stringify(true)).then(() => {
      this.setState({ isBellActive: true});
    });
  }

  setFalse(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem('isBellActive', JSON.stringify(false)).then(() => {
      this.setState({ isBellActive: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <Ionicons

        name={this.state.isBellActive? "md-notifications":"md-notifications-off"}
        color={"white"}
        size={30}
        style={styles.NotifIcon}
        onPress={() => {       
            Vibration.vibrate()
             if(this.state.isBellActive == false){             
                  PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
                    userInfo:{
                      ID: this.state.ID
                    },
                    alertTitle: "Launching Soon:",
                    alertBody: this.state.alertBody,
                    fireDate: this.state.fireDate // in 30 mins
                    });
                    this.setTrue()
                    this.setState({Key:true})
                  }
                  else if(this.state.isBellActive != false){
                    PushNotificationIOS.cancelLocalNotifications({ID:this.state.ID});
                    this.setFalse()
                  }
                }
            }
         }}
       />
    );
  }
}
```

**Class that calls Component**

```
export default class LaunchingScreen extends React.Component{
 let launches = this.state.dataSource.map((item, key) => {
   ..
   <View>
    ..
    <Bell />
    ..
   </View>
     ..
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is in class that calls components, it gets a JSON that has all the info:

```
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch("https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/20")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.launches
        }); 
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

[image: Picture of an item and it's bell]

Comment: Since every `Bell` component is accessing the same key `isBellActive` in `AsyncStorage`, on relaunch every component is having the last updated value. You need to separate the `AsyncStorage`'s  key for every component. How does the `dataSource` record look like, do they have any uniquely identifiable property?

Comment: datasource gets a JSON file from an API, and each list that is created has its own name that's different from each other... ill post a picture and what the code looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the response from the API shared by you, it looks like that `id` property is unique and you can use that property to uniquely define `key` for `Bell` component and used that `key` to store/retrieve data from `AsyncStorage`. Please consider following code snippets

Change **LaunchingScreen** to add `key={item.id}`

```
export default class LaunchingScreen extends React.Component{
  let launches = this.state.dataSource.map((item, key) => {
    ..
    <View>
    ..
    <Bell key={item.id}/>
    ..
    </View>
    ..
  }
}
```

Now in the `Bell` component, use the key property to access data from `AsyncStorage`

```
export default class Bell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
      isBellActive:  null
    };
    this.accessKey = `${props.key}-isBellActive`;
  }

  componentDidMount = ()=>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.accessKey).then(value => this.setState({ isBellActive: JSON.parse(value) }));
  }

  setTrue(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem(this.accessKey, JSON.stringify(true)).then(() => {
      this.setState({ isBellActive: true});
    });
  }

  setFalse(){
    AsyncStorage.setItem(this.accessKey, JSON.stringify(false)).then(() => {
      this.setState({ isBellActive: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
     return (
      <Ionicons

        name={this.state.isBellActive? "md-notifications":"md-notifications-off"}
        color={"white"}
        size={30}
        style={styles.NotifIcon}
        onPress={() => {       
            Vibration.vibrate()
             if(this.state.isBellActive == false){             
                  PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
                    userInfo:{
                      ID: this.state.ID
                    },
                    alertTitle: "Launching Soon:",
                    alertBody: this.state.alertBody,
                    fireDate: this.state.fireDate // in 30 mins
                    });
                    this.setTrue()
                    this.setState({Key:true})
                  }
                  else if(this.state.isBellActive != false){
                    PushNotificationIOS.cancelLocalNotifications({ID:this.state.ID});
                    this.setFalse()
                  }
                }
            }
         }}
       />
    );
  }
}
```

In the above component, we are first deciding the access key using **this.accessKey = `${props.key}-isBellActive`;** and then using `this.accessKey` instead of `isBellActive`.

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: The code you provided worked, to an extent. The props.key had an undefined tag (but I think that's just because item.ID is some how undefined? idk) So I changed props.key to this.props.ID (props.ID just gets the title of the rocket launch and not a number) and that seemed to fixed it. (there was an error but it seemed to resolve itself- edit)

Comment: Ok well the error I mentioned in my comment seemed to not resolve itself. The problem that is happening is that I have to tap on the icon twice INITIALLY for it to change from off to on but then only once after (and only once even if I close the app etc). I believe it has to do with how isBellActive is initialized but I changed it from null to false but that didn't fix it. I also tried doing an if statement in the componentDidMount to see if isBellActive true/false/null and if not then set isBellActive to false. That worked but it always reverted back to false after closing the app.

Comment: What value you are getting for `JSON.parse(value)`, is it string or boolean, I guess it is boolean? Also, do you need `else if(this.state.isBellActive != false)` check, I believe only `else` will work?

Comment: I put a .then after the getItem to find what it gives, its undefined at first. I then put a getItem under the first getItem in componentDidMount and it returns a boolean false. and I tried using an else not else if and the problem still persisted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same component multiple times and want to have a different state for each of them then you have to set `key` property for each component.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

For this kind of situation where you want to use the same component multiple times, you have to set `key` property. Otherwise, each component will have the same state.